# Binary file IO in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

EDIT: **TLDR** In C family languages you can represent arbitrary data ( ints, floats, doubles, structs ) as byte streams via casting and pack them into streams or buffers. And you can do the reverse to get data back out. And of course you can byte swap for endianness correctness.

Is this possible in idiomatic swift?

*Now the original question:*

If I were writing in C/C++/ObjC I might cast a struct to unsigned char * and write its bytes to a FILE*, or memcpy them to a buffer. Same for ints, doubles, etc. I know there are endianness concerns to deal with, but this is for an iOS app, and I don't expect endianness to change any time soon for the platform. Swift's type system doesn't seem like it would allow this behavior ( casting arbitrary data to unsigned 8 bit ints and passing the address ), but I don't know.

I'm learning Swift, and would like an idiomatic way to write my data. Note that my highly numeric, and ultimately going to be sent over the wire so it needs to be compact, so textual formats like JSON are out.

I *could* use NSKeyedArchiver but I want to learn here. Also I don't want to write off an android client at some point in the future so a simple binary coding seems where it's at.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there a structure to your data? Could you just use Core Data? Or how about NSData? Are you asking how to invent a format or how to write some preexisting data to a file? The former is probably too broad a question for SO.

Comment: I've made my own binary formats many times - that's not the problem. The problem is how, in idiomatic swift, to pass things like Ints and Doubles to byte streams. I intend to use NSData as a way to represent the *bytes* in memory ( and to provide persistence ) but I can't figure out how in Swift to get values in and out. This would be trivial in C/ObjC/C++

Comment: `NSKeyedArchiver` *is* the idiomatic way to serialize data in Swift.

Answer (score 5):

As noted [in *Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C*](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_15), you can pass/assign an array of a Swift type to a parameter/variable of pointer type, and vice versa, to get a binary representation. This even works if you define your own `struct` types, much like in C.

Here's an example -- I use code like this for packaging up 3D vertex data for the GPU (with SceneKit, OpenGL, etc.):

```
struct Float3 {
    var x, y, z: GLfloat
}
struct Vertex {
    var position, normal: Float3
}

var vertices: [Vertex] // initialization omitted for brevity
let data = NSData(bytes: vertices, length: vertices.count * sizeof(Vertex))
```

Inspect this data and you'll see a pattern of 32 * 3 * 2 bits of IEEE 754 floating-point numbers (just like you'd get from serializing a C struct through pointer access).

For going the other direction, you might sometimes need `unsafeBitCast`.

If you're using this for data persistence, be sure to check or enforce endianness.

Comment: I don't believe that Swift makes any promises about the alignment of these values (which is also a problem in C and C++). It's possible that there can be garbage between your fields, and that the layout may be different when you read a serialized version. The problem is pretty much identical in C/C++; but it's another thing beyond endianness that can burn you with reading raw memory.

Answer (score 4):

The kind of format you're discussing is well explored with [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org). There are a few early attempts at doing this in Swift:

- https://github.com/briandw/SwiftPack
- https://github.com/yageek/SwiftMsgPack

I'd probably start with the yageek version. In particular, look at how packing is done into `[Byte]` data structures. I'd say this is pretty idiomatic Swift, without losing endian management (which you shouldn't ignore; chips do change, and the numeric types give you via `bigEndian`):

```
extension Int32 : MsgPackMarshable{
  public func msgpack_marshal() -> Array<Byte>{

        let bigEndian: UInt32 = UInt32(self.bigEndian)
        return [0xce, Byte((bigEndian & 0xFF000000) >> 24), Byte((bigEndian & 0xFF0000) >> 16), Byte((bigEndian & 0xFF00) >> 8), Byte(bigEndian & 0x00FF)]
    }
}
```

This is also fairly similar to how you'd write it in C or C++ if you were managing byte order (which C and C++ should *always* do, so the fact that they *could* splat their bytes into memory doesn't make correct implementations trivial). I'd probably drop `Byte` (which comes from Foundation) and use `UInt8` (which is defined in core Swift). But either is fine. And of course it's more idiomatic to say `[UInt8]` rather than `Array<UInt8>`.

That said, as Zaph notes, `NSKeyedArchiver` is idiomatic for Swift. But that doesn't mean MessagePack isn't a good format for this kind of problem, and it's very portable.